# Subscribe Angular2 events on derived class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I'm developing an application which makes use of several grids across different pages. Instead of rewriting HTML again and again, I abstracted the code in the following way:

**table.component.ts**

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit{
  columns: Column[]= [];
  rows: any[] = [];
  searchText: string;
  routerLinked: string;
  showFilter: boolean;

  constructor(private paginService: PaginationService,
              private tableLoader: GridLoadUtil,
              private progressBarService: ProgressBarService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
    this.paginService.itemsToDisplayChange.subscribe((value) => {
      this.rows = value
    });

    this.tableLoader.columnsChange.subscribe((values) => {
      this.columns = values;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableLoader.beforeDataLoaded();
    this.progressBarService.startProgress();
    this.routerLinked = this.route.snapshot.url[0].path + '/';
    this.showFilter = true;
  }

  navigateToCreate() {
    this.router.navigate([this.routerLinked]);
  }

  applyFilter() {
    this.paginService.applyFilter(this.searchText);
  }

  clearFilter() {
    this.searchText = '';
    this.paginService.clearFilter();
  }
}
```

**table.component.html**

```
<div class="container container-fluid">
  <div class="row" *ngIf="showFilter === true">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Filter </label>
      <input type="text" id="inputName" [(ngModel)]="searchText"/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" (click)="applyFilter()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" (click)="clearFilter()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" (click)="navigateToCreate()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column.header}}</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of rows;trackBy: trackByID;">
        <td *ngFor="let column of columns">{{row[column.field]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <xfd-progressbar component></xfd-progressbar>
  <div class="row col-lg-offset-5">
    <ngbd-pagination-basic> component</ngbd-pagination-basic>
  </div>
</div>
```

My table components takes in various services as dependencies, like paginService for pagination implementation, progressBar, routers etc. It also makes use of GridLoadUtil, which provides information about the columns the grid will have, as well as passes the data to it.

**GridLoadUtil**

```
@Injectable()
export class GridLoadUtil {
  columns: Column[] = [];
  columnsChange: Subject<Column[]> = new Subject<Column[]>();

  constructor(protected paginService: PaginationService) {
  }

  setColumns(columnList: Column[]): void {
    this.columns = columnList;
    this.columnsChange.next(this.columns);
  }

  beforeDataLoaded(): void {
    this.paginService.setPaginationDisabled(true);
    this.paginService.setTotalItems([]);
  }

  afterDataLoaded(data): void {
    this.paginService.setTotalItems(data);
    this.paginService.setPaginationDisabled((data.length == 0));
    this.paginService.setActivePage(1);
  }
}
```

If I have multiple grids on the same page, I'm using directives to provide a new implementation of GridLoadUtil, so that all grids are not impacted because of change in one.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dummy]',
  providers: [{provide: GridLoadUtil, useClass: DummyGridLoadUtil}]
})
export class DummyDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.error("not")
  }
}
```

This is what my page looks like if it has multiple grids -

```
 <xfd-table></xfd-table>

 <xfd-table [dummy]></xfd-table>
```

I have managed to get both tables behaving differently. However, the changes to columns for the second grid are not getting subscribed and hence don't appear on the page. Even though table.component.ts gets an instance of DummyGridLoadUtil injected,

```
this.tableLoader.columnsChange.subscribe((values) => {
      this.columns = values;
});
```

The above part subscribes to changes on the type of the variable(GridLoadUtil) rather than the implementation(DummyGridLoadUtil).

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: why can't the table component just provide the gridloadutil? I don't understand the need for the dummy directive provider.

Comment: XYProblem? The whole setup seems a bit weird to me. maybe overthink what you actually want to achieve and ask about how the best way to achieve this would be.

Comment: @bryan60 - Table Component is for rendering tables across different pages. GridLoadUtil is set up by each page, with the right set of columns it needs and the tableLoader just loads them. This way TableLoader is agnostic to the page its being used on. Works perfectly if there is just one table per page

Comment: @Lexith - I'm planning to rethink. Its just that this setup reduced redundant code perfectly. So extending it is my first choice.

Comment: OK, so you're providing the gridLoadUtil in the page component wrapping it and then using the page component to set the columns... this is a definite design flaw if you need to have more than one per page.  Your only option without restructuring is to create table wrappers within pages that provide the grid load util and the services needed to populate the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a serious design flaw if you want more than one table per page.

right now it seems like:

page has services to load data and provides grid load util

table component gets that grid load util injected and then the page wrapper calls methods to set columns

You're attempting to re-provide the gridloadutil with a dummy directive, but of course there is no way for the page wrapper to call the methods on in since it is lower in the injector tree.

What you have to do, without restructuring, is create wrappers for each table when you want to have multiple on a page.

so TableOneWrapperComponent that provides grid load util and has whatever service needed to populate it, and TableTwoWrapperComponent that provides it's own copy of grid load util and has whatever service needed to provide it.

Otherwise, you could consider minor restructuring so the columns are fed as inputs rather than via service, since it seems like a direct parent / child relationship.  However, each component gets one copy of a given service, so you cannot have a parent communicate to two children via the same service independently.

Answer (score -1):

I went ahead with the change in my design. I didn't truly change a lot

**Table.component.ts**

```
import {Column} from "../models/Column";
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {PaginationService} from "../services/PaginationService";
import {GridLoadUtil} from "../util/GridLoadUtil";
import {ProgressBarService} from "../services/ProgressBarService";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {NgbProgressbarConfig} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

/**
 * Created by ppandey on 6/12/2017.
 */

@Component({
    selector: 'xfd-table',
    templateUrl: './table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./table.component.css'],
    providers: [PaginationService, GridLoadUtil, ProgressBarService]
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit{
  get columns(): Column[] {
    return this.tableLoader.columns;
  }

  @Input()
  set columns (cols: Column[]) {
    this.tableLoader.setColumns(cols);
  }

  get totalRows(): any[] {
    return this.paginService.getTotalItems();
  }

  @Input()
  set totalRows (row: any[]) {
    this.afterDataLoaded(row);
    this.progressBarService.endProgress();
  }


  rows: any[] = [];
  searchText: string;
  routerLinked: string;
  showFilter: boolean;

  constructor(private paginService: PaginationService,
              private tableLoader: GridLoadUtil,
              private progressBarService: ProgressBarService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
    this.paginService.itemsToDisplayChange.subscribe((value) => {
      this.rows = value
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.beforeDataLoaded();
    this.progressBarService.startProgress();
    this.routerLinked = this.route.snapshot.url[0].path.replace('Grid', '') + '/';
    this.showFilter = true;
  }

  beforeDataLoaded(): void {
    this.paginService.setPaginationDisabled(true);
    this.paginService.setTotalItems([]);
  }

  afterDataLoaded(data): void {
    this.paginService.setTotalItems(data);
    this.paginService.setPaginationDisabled((data.length == 0));
    this.paginService.setActivePage(1);
  }

  navigateToCreate() {
    this.router.navigate([this.routerLinked]);
  }

  navigateToEdit(row) {
    this.router.navigate([this.routerLinked + row.userId]);
  }

  applyFilter() {
    this.paginService.applyFilter(this.searchText);
  }

  clearFilter() {
    this.searchText = '';
    this.paginService.clearFilter();
  }
}
```

I'm now using Hierarchial DI, to provide the columns and rows from the parent component. For multiple tables on the same page, I've put each table in a component of its own, which makes sense, because each table represents different data and a different section.

On each parent component, here's what I do -

```
<xfd-table [columns]="sourceTableGridColumns" [totalRows]="sourceTableGridData"></xfd-table>

<xfd-table [columns]="sourceDatabaseGridColumns" [totalRows]="sourceDatabaseGridData"></xfd-table>
```

This solves a problem! And my code is still very configurable and reusable.

Comment: kinda feel like you used my suggested restructure

Comment: There you go then!